# tiny carousel width

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a little problem with the width of the tiny carousel. I implemented the carousel in this page: http://www.srvppal.com/testcontexport/

as you can see the fourth image in the carousel is cutted, I am trying to increase the width of the viewport but if I do that the buttons disappear, this is the css.

```
#slider2 .viewport {
 margin-left:1px;
 float: left;
 height: 215px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 862px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a left padding on ul.overview. Remove it with:

```
ul.overview{padding-left:0}
```

This should remove your problem

Comment: Thank you so much Topek, I didn´t know how to remove that padding.